# Import classes from child directory python

Tags: python, python-import

I've been trying to import some python classes which are defined in a child directory. The directory structure is as follows:

```
workspace/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    checker/
       __init__.py
       baseChecker.py
       gChecker.py
```

The `baseChecker.py` looks similar to:

```
import urllib
class BaseChecker(object):
    # SOME METHODS HERE
```

The `gChecker.py` file:

```
import baseChecker # should import baseChecker.py
class GChecker(BaseChecker): # gives a TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    # SOME METHODS WHICH USE URLLIB
```

And finally the `main.py` file:

```
import ?????
gChecker = GChecker()
gChecker.someStuff() # which uses urllib
```

My intention is to be able to run `main.py` file and call instantiate the classes under the `checker/` directory. But I would like to avoid importing urllib from each file (if it is possible).

Note that both the `__init__.py` are empty files.

I have already tried calling `from checker.gChecker import GChecker` in `main.py` but a `ImportError: No module named checker.gChecker` shows.

Comment: How are you running main.py? Python needs to know where to find the `checker` module, so to do `import checker.gChecker`, you would need to have it in your `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the posted code, in `gChecker.py`, you need to do

```
from baseChecker import BaseChecker
```

instead of `import baseChecker`
Otherwise you get

> `NameError: name 'BaseChecker' is not defined`

Also with the mentioned folders structure you don't need `checker` module to be in the `PYTHONPATH` in order to be visible by `main.py`
Then in `main.y` you can do:

```
from checker import gChecker.GChecker
```

Comment: But that makes me `import urllib` in both files, isn't there a way to import it only once?

Comment: In `python` each time you use a module you have to add the related import. This has nothing to do with the error that you are getting.

Comment: What if there were some methods in `baseChecker.py`? Doing `from baseChecker import BaseChecker` only imports the class, if I'm not mistaken, right?

Comment: Yeah it only import the Class. If you want everything in `baseChecker` you need to do `import baseChecker.*` then you can use directly the functions and classes names. You can also di  `import base checker` then whenever you use a function that is in `basechecker.py` e.g ; func1 you need  to do base `basechecker.func_name` or `basechecker.class_name` e.g: `basechecker.func1` or in your current use case `basechecker. BaseChecker`

Comment: Thanks! What about importing the checker module from `main.py`?

Comment: @lpares12 Edited the answer with the import in `main.py`, If useful please up vote and/or accept to also help others to find the right answer.

Comment: Thanks again! Though `from checker import GChecker` shouldn't it be `from checker import gChecker` and then instantiate the object as `gChecker.GChecker`?